# String with numbers add them Java

Tags: java, string

I'm getting a string which contains numbers,

Eg:- `123312351863`

which is the best method to separate each number and add them together?

as example total `38`

Comment: Ohh please post your effort here.. having 1k+ reputation, why this kind of low quality post?

Comment: Hash: you can't. for instance, the first number COULD be 1, it could also be 12, or 123, or ....

Answer (score 5):

I will not give you the *exact answer*.

> 1. Parse the entire String as an Integer using `Integer.parseInt()` or `Long.parseLong()` . Based on appropriate *size*.
> 2. You can add each digit by using the following 2 operators -> `/` and  `%`.
> 3. You will also need a `while` loop.

Note : This approach fails for very large numbers or if the number starts with `0`. You can indeed do it using `charAt()` + some other string methodd.

Comment: Plus 1 although I wouldn't have bothered to answer given the context.

Comment: Fails for values larger than 2^31

Comment: So, what if the first number is 12, not 1? or 1233, for that matter? This might be correct, it might be incomplete, depending on additional information the OP could(should) provide

Comment: Long.parseLong() still fails for values larger than 2^63

Comment: @amit - Of course. I was just showing him a simple way. He could use a `for` loop and *iterate* through the char array and keep converting the values to int and add them.

Comment: @Stultuske - Yes. This will also fail when the string starts with `0`... I was just showing a way.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Simple {
    public static void main(String `args`[]){  
        String str = "123456789";
        Integer total = 0;
        for (Character eachNumber : str.toCharArray()) {
            total += Integer.parseInt(eachNumber.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A short way in Java 8:

```
String s = "123312351863";
int sum = s.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
int res = 0;
String s= "123312351863";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
{
    String str= ""+s.charAt(i);
    int b =  Integer.parseInt(str);
    res = res + b;
}

System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: This is unacceptable. Is this question worth to have this answer ?

Comment: I am upvoting the answer not because to compensate downvote but this answer is useful as per mouse hover say when I point on uparrow

Answer (score 0):

You can first split the string to single characters using [`String.split("")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) (note it will give an empty string at the beginning for prior to java8 versions)

Then, iterate the `String[]`, [parse each number to `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer(java.lang.String)), and sum them

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by "" , then convert each string to Integer and sum the numbers. E.g. in java 8

```
 System.out.println(Stream.of(s).map(x -> x.split("")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum());
```

Output

```
38
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter. There is no harsh rule for downvote. If any one sees answer is useful just upvote else downvote. I would have upvoted your answer but I dont have java 8 in my machine.so cant test your code

Comment: @SpringLearner you can view the output here http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/553e2b0ce4b0d45eaf6fb45f , no need for installation . B/w its always nice if some explain why they are downvoting.

Comment: yes it would be nice if they give any reason but unfortunately they dont.

Comment: the link you gave is not working

Comment: @Try this one https://ideone.com/G3cyE5

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

1. Iterate over the charaters of string using `loop` and `chatAt()`.
2. Convert the character to int values using `Character.getNumericValue(yourChar)`.
3. Then sum up the int values.

Answer (score -1):

I would try as below

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String x="123312351863";
    String r[]=x.split("");int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=x.length();i++)
    {

        sum+=Integer.parseInt(r[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Did not downvote, but all "code only" answers here were downvoted. A code only answers has very little value to actually teach, it is giving the OP a fish, rather than teaching him how to fish.

Comment: @amit This is a simple answer,Had it been a question for a new comer or whose reps is low,I would not have answered. But OP has good amount of reps.

Comment: This question not deserve to have an answer in full. having 7k+ reputation you should know that.